How to Clear Unread Notifications for a Deleted Repository on GitHub?
I previously followed a repository on GitHub that has now been deleted, but there are still many unread notifications related to this repository that I can't mark as read. I can't even view these notifications, yet GitHub keeps reminding me about pending notifications. How can I clear these notifications?
Notification page:

I've already set the repository to "Stop ignoring" on the "Watching" settings page, but the notifications persist.

My 'Notifications/Subscriptions' list is empty.


In the left sidebar, under the list of repositories, select the "Manage notifications" dropdown menu and click Subscriptions. Select the notifications you want to unsubscribe from. In the top right, click Unsubscribe.

My 'Notifications/Subscriptions' list is empty.

This issue has been resolved. Those with similar problems can refer to the solution

Go to Done
Select all (checkbox)
Move to inbox (button)
Go to inbox
Select all (checkbox)
Select all X (blue link)
Done (button)

